# variable vals from within async function to other js file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

I am trying to *export my variable values* that populate from within a `async function` in .js file 1 (i.e. /events.js) to another function in .js file 2 (i.e. app/loader.js)

**./events.js**

```
 async function mapViewClickHandler(event) {
        // get coords A

        var coordinatesAx;
        var coordinatesAy;

        var coordinatesAx = ntoResults[0].mapPoint.latitude;
        var coordinatesAy = ntoResults[0].mapPoint.longitude;

        var mapPointCoordsA = coordinatesAx + "," + coordinatesAy;
        console.log("start coords A:" + mapPointCoordsA);

        // end get coords A
        .............
  }
```

**./loader.js**

```
function initPoints(evt) { 

        // need to bring vals here
        var mapPointCoordsA = coordinatesAx + "," + coordinatesAy; 
        console.log("start coords A:" + mapPointCoordsA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, unless you look after dynamic import/exports.

Otherwise you want to call one function in the other's context and pass the result.

But why is this function async? I mean you arent waiting for any promise, you could just do it synchronously.

you could subscribe to the mapClicks with the first function, in the context of the second for example.

Comment: I couldn't set a global variable then update it from within my async function; then export? There is more code in the async function, there are thousands of click points.............